# Can someone make clear the concept of a "restricted metric"

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, terminology, definition

I never understood this concept of restricted metric. Consider the following theorem.

[image]

http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M403/Notes403_4.pdf

I don't quite understand this concept since under usual circumstances when working with $\mathbb{R}^n$, take any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then we can simply equip the subset with the Euclidean distance as in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here it is pointless to talk about the restriction, because it is understood that the metric is now defined on the Cartesian product of the subset. I have never seen anyone making this distinction.

> Can someone demonstrate a case where $S$ a subset of $(M,d)$, where
>   the restricted metric $d|_S$ can be quite different than the "ambient"
>   metric $d$?

Comment: The restricted metric **is** the "ambient" metric - that's just the word we use to formally refer to it.

Comment: You might be overthinking the concept of "restriction". Given any function $f : A \to B$ and any subset $C \subset A$, there is a restriction function $f | C$. Evaluation of $f | C$ uses the exact same formula as evaluation of $f$, the only difference being that one may plug any element of $A$ into $f$, whereas one may only plug elements of $C$ into $f | C$. Thus, one may plug any ordered pair $(x_1,x_2)$ in $X \times X$ into the formula for $d$; but with $d_Y$, while one uses the same formula to evaluate, one may only plug in those ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ which are in $Y \times Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that the metric on $Y$ is a *function* $d_Y\colon Y\times Y\to [0,\infty)$. The "original" metric $d_X$ is a function $d_X\colon X\times X\to [0,\infty)$.

You have $d_Y(u,v) = d_X(u,v)$ for every $(u,v) \in Y\times Y$, but that does not mean the two functions are the same: they coincide on every point of $Y\times Y$, but they do not have the same domain. They are not formally the same mathematical object.

In particular, if $Y\subsetneq X$ and $u,v\in X\setminus Y$, then $d_X(u,v)$ is defined, but $d_Y(u,v)$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "distinction". Well, consider $X = \mathbb R$ with the Euclidian metric and $Y = [0,1]$. Then, for example, $[0,1]$ is open in the metric space $Y$, while it is not in $X$. The same holds for sets of the type $[0,x)$, where $x\in (0,1)$. Or: If you take $Y = (0,1)$ then $Y$ is not complete while $X$ is. So, suddenly sequences do not have limits which they had before.